# How to let grub display all kernels

Tags: grub2, kernel, virtualbox

As I have some issue with VirtualBox and I know that it is because of the current kernel `5.3.0.28`, I decided to boot in `4.18.0.20`, which supports VM. I checked my available kernels and I do see it is there.

[image]

However as I boot into the grub, I can only see the latest ones (`5.3.0.28` and `5.3.0.26`(no screenshot in grub).

Comment: You could do an `update-grub`. See what that gives you ...

Comment: Also note that you're only showing the kernel modules in your picture above. The actual kernel images should be located in your `/boot` directory instead ...

Comment: The first doesn't help, the second indeed only shows the lastest two, do you know how should I update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only have those 2 kernel versions available in `/boot` there is no surprise `grub` only lists those. You seem to have the modules installed for a lot of different kernel versions, but without the actual kernel image grub will (obviously) not generate a menu entry for them.

Since you have the kernel modules for those particular versions, I can only guess the kernel was installed at some point, but removed later on.

Simply installing `linux-image-<version>-generic` should do the trick and it should also update the `grub` menu for you.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that the system only automatically keeps two kernels. But it's strange though that I work in parallel on my laptop and desktop, my desktop keeps previous three kernels but laptop doesn't. But anyway, I will figure it out.

Comment: It's not working. Trying to boot from kernel 5.4 (current 5.8). I had installed 5.4.77 version but it not appear in grub menu. Command `sudo update-grub` also not helping.

Comment: Reinstall of that kernel helped me, it did appear. But unfortunately I couldn't load with this kernel.